# How can I improve my method with less lines?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a method that works out fine though I am still wondering if it could be improved with less lines. I have documented the method with comments directly in the code, so I guess it should be clear what it does!

I appreciate every suggestion! Thx in advance!

```
//FULL PROPERTY FOR BINDING IN VIEW.XAML
private string _liederlisteAnzeige;
public string LiederlisteAnzeige
{
    get 
    { 
        return _liederlisteAnzeige; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        _liederlisteAnzeige = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void LiedEinfuegen()
{
    //CREATE A LIST OF CLASS LIED AND FILL WITH ACCESS-DATABASE TABLE
    Liederliste = new List<Lied>();
    Liederliste = AccessTabellen.GetAllTableData(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM " + AusgewaehlteTabelle.Tabellenname);

    //CREATE ANOTHER LIST AND FILL ONLY WITH PROPERTY LIEDERNUMMER OF LIST LIEDERLISTE BY LOOPING 
    List<string> LiederlisteLiedernamen = new List<string>();
    foreach (Lied lied in Liederliste)
    {
        if (lied.Liedernummer == AusgewaehltesLied.Liedernummer)
        {
            LiederlisteLiedernamen.Add(lied.Liedername);
        } 
    }

    //CREATE 3rd LIST TO REMOVE ALL DUPLICATES FROM LIST No2
    List<string> LiederlisteOhneDuplikate = new List<string>();
    LiederlisteOhneDuplikate = LiederlisteLiedernamen.Distinct().ToList();

    //LOOP THROUGH 3rd LIST AND CREATE A STRING (LIEDERLISTEANZEIGE) WITH STRINGBUILDER. THE STRING VARIABLE  WILL BE THEN BINDED TO VIEW.XAML CONTROL 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in LiederlisteOhneDuplikate)
    {
        sb.Append(item).AppendLine();
    }
    if (LiederlisteAnzeige == null)
    {
        LiederlisteAnzeige = sb.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        LiederlisteAnzeige += sb.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Fastest way to reduce some lines is to not initialize your Lists to empty lists, and then assign them again.  You can safely delete the line `Liederliste = new List<Lied>();`, for example.   That said, fewer lines is not always best - sometimes, having more lines makes the code easier to read, and easier to maintain.  See [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203684/is-fewer-lines-of-code-always-better/203686) at the Software Engineering Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Thank you Sel! This would be my next question: can you give me an example for 'more lines == easier to read and to maintain'. :-)

Comment: `someobject.doSomething(someSingleton.getInstance().with().a().lot().of().law().of().demeter().violations()).and().if().that().werent().enough().theres().more();`  Stolen from second answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185925/how-important-is-it-to-reduce-the-number-of-lines-in-code).  This is just one (absurd) example, but it highlights how separating onto more lines can make things more readable, easier to debug, etc.  If you web search for this topic of code readability and maintenance, I think you will find lots of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a little shorter actually, because you can use linq to cut out the intermediate lists.

Note that your dynamic query may be prone to sql injection attacks. Unless the `Tabellenname` property is compiled in your code, I would not use that property in the select query.

```
public void LiedEinfuegen()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Use linq to iterate over the list with the filters inline, that way you dont't need to initialize intermediate lists.
    foreach (var item in AccessTabellen.GetAllTableData(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM " + AusgewaehlteTabelle.Tabellenname)
        .Where(l => l.Liedernummer == AusgewaehltesLied.Liedernummer)
        .Distinct())
    {
        sb.AppendLine(item);
    }

    // If you initialize LiederlisteAnzeige with an empty string "", you don't need the if null check.
    LiederlisteAnzeige += sb.ToString();
}
```

EDIT:
If you combine this with Selim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61129197/3883866), you could do this thing in one line, however, it will affect the readability a bit:

```
LiederlisteAnzeige += string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine, 
    AccessTabellen.GetAllTableData(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM " + AusgewaehlteTabelle.Tabellenname)
        .Where(l => l.Liedernummer == AusgewaehltesLied.Liedernummer)
        .Select(s => s.Liedername)
        .Distinct());
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, thank you for the linq statement. Didn't know it's possible to include it already into a foreach loop. That's awesome!

Comment: You're assuming the Liederliste property needs to be set as well. Why should this be required? As a binding property in a view.xaml I guess?! In this case it's not needed...

Comment: @Robert Updated my answer. If you don't need the `Liederliste` property, you can put it all in a single statement.

Comment: This line of code looks great though doesn't it access the database with every loop? I would think this would cost performance, doesn't it?

Comment: No, that query will be executed only once.

Comment: Awesome! One line remaining of the original Code! PS: I will just have to add .Select to the Linq-Query

Comment: @Robert don't forget to mark as the answer if this answers your question.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I would like to come back on the SQL Injection: the variable Tabellenname is binded to a Combobox, therefore it should be ok to use a dynamic query in this case. As far I understood it could be dangerous when the variable would pull out its data from a textbox for instance, as you could type in the name of the database and manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq) more and [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) helps you to do this. So that you don't need to write foreach loops that much.

```
public static void LiedEinfuegen()
{
    Liederliste = AccessTabellen.GetAllTableData(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM " + AusgewaehlteTabelle.Tabellenname);

    List<string> LiederlisteOhneDuplikate = Liederliste.Where(i => i.Liedernummer == AusgewaehltesLied.Liedernummer)
                                                    .Select(s => s.Liedername).Distinct().ToList();

    var calculatedString = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, LiederlisteOhneDuplikate);

    LiederlisteAnzeige = LiederlisteAnzeige == null ? calculatedString : (LiederlisteAnzeige + calculatedString);
}
```

Comment: Hi Selim, I like your code very much -> way less typing. I am very lazy in this regard. Thx!

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped you please mark answer as accepted so that it helps the others.